# Ссылка на viber не работает на устройстве mac

Tags: html, mac, viber

Подскажите, почему данная ссылка работает только, если установлен вайбер на устройство?  `<a href="viber://chat?number=+1234567890">viber</a>`
Если не установлен вайбер, то по нажатию на компьютере ничего не происходит, а если открыть на mac, пишет: `safari не может открыть указанный адрес, т.к. не расспознаёт ссылки, начинающиеся с viber://`
на андроиде просит обновить вайбер, хотя вроде обновлен.
Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы хотя-бы писало, что установите `viber` или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: операционная система не имеет ни малейшего представления, что такое viber (да и не нужно ей этого знать). Поэтому, она не может предложить, где скачать его. Распознать ссылки будет только после того, как соответствующее приложение зарегистрирует данную схему. То, что просит обновить вайбер - вполне может быть, что у Вас установлено приложение, которое также зарегистрировало эту схему и пытается поставить какую-либо гадость.

Comment: @KoVadim, а как зарегистрировать эту схему? т.е. это нормальное поведение браузера? не ошибка?

Comment: зарегистрировать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so
да, это правильное, адекватное поведение браузера